# Dynamically generated bash select menu - update menu items when one or more are removed

Tags: bash, shell, menu

I have an array **pkgLangs** which contains a number of items (strings) that the user has selected from a previous selection menu (top-level).

One of the selection options in the top-level menu leads to a sub-menu where the user can remove items from **pkgLangs**. The menu is build like this:

```
declare -a pkgLangsBackup="${pkgLangs[@]}" # Backup the array in case the user cancels the removal operation
pkgLangs+=("Accept" "Cancel")
select pkgLang in "${pkgLangs[@]}"
do
  if [[ "$pkgLang" == "Accept" ]]
  then
    echo "Changes have been accepted"
    # Remove the "Accept" and "Cancel" from the array to reverse it to a semantically correct state (containing languages only!)
    unset pkgLangs[${#pkgLangs[@]}-1] # Remove the "Accept"
    unset pkgLangs[${#pkgLangs[@]}-1] # Remove the "Cancel"
    break
  elif [[ "$pkgLang" == "Cancel" ]]
  then
    echo "Changes have been cancelled"
    pkgLangs=( $pkgLangsBackup )
    break
  else
    echo "Removed $pkgLang from supported languages"
    pkgLangs=( ${pkgLangs[@]/"$pkgLang"} )  # Using only this here removes the selected properly!
    echo "New list of supported languages: "
    arg_display pkgLangs
  fi
done
```

As you can see it is dynamically generated based on the contents of that array. I use this method for creating a selection menu because I do not know which items were selected in the previous menu level and added to this menu. The removal of items is done in the ELSE block. The "Cancel" is handled in the ELIF block and accordingly the "Accept" - in the IF block.

The problem I'm having is the way things are displayed. Currently only when I re-enter this menu the new state of the list is used to create the set of options the user can choose from. I would like to dynamically re-generate the menu on the fly.

Example:

**CURRENT STATE:**

```
pkgLangs: "A" "B" "C" "D"
--> Entering the sub-menu
pkgLangs: "A" "B" "C" "D" "Accept" "Cancel"
--> Generate the sub-menu from pkgLangs:
  1) A
  2) B
  3) C
  4) D
  5) Accept
  6) Cancel
--> User removes B:
pkgLangs: "A" "C" "D" "Accept" "Cancel"
--> User sees again the following sub-menu:
  1) A
  2) B <---------- This is however no longer in pkgLangs!
  3) C
  4) D
  5) Accept
  6) Cancel
```

Of course even if the user selects B) this will not cause an error because of the way the array works - if the item is not found there, it also cannot be removed hence nothing happens.

**DESIRED STATE:**

```
pkgLangs: "A" "B" "C" "D"
--> Entering the sub-menu
pkgLangs: "A" "B" "C" "D" "Accept" "Cancel"
--> Generate the sub-menu from pkgLangs:
  1) A
  2) B
  3) C
  4) D
  5) Accept
  6) Cancel
--> User removes B:
pkgLangs: "A" "C" "D" "Accept" "Cancel"
--> User now sees the following sub-menu (note also that the numbering has also acknowledged the changes!):
  1) A
  2) C
  3) D
  4) Accept
  5) Cancel
```

I'm new to bash scripting and there is probably some wacky one-liner that more advanced users will probably throw at me but I would like to know how I can modify THIS code in particular to suite the needs of the users who will use it.

From what I see the select loop generates it's structure once and after that you loop through it. That's why changes during the looping that concern this structure are simply ignored and only when the structure is re-generated the result shows.

Hope it's clear what I mean. If you have further questions I'll do whatever I can to answer these.

Thanks!

Comment: By the way: Don't add "Accept" and "Cancel" to array pkgLangs. Use `select pkgLang in "${pkgLangs[@]}" "Accept" "Cancel"` and there is no need to remove them from array pkgLangs.

Comment: Maybe this helps you: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Thanks for the tip with adding the "Accept" and "Cancel". I totally forgot you can add stuff on the fly. :) As for the debugging - yeah, I know how to debug but this does not change the way the select loop works. I'm looking for a workaround.